# How to resize an SVG by changing the SVG without CSS

Tags: svg

How do you resize an SVG without using CSS by just changing the SVG itself.

Here is my SVG and I'd like for it to be 17x17

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="420px" height="420px"  fill="none" stroke="#dcdcdc">
    <path stroke-width="26" d="M209,15a195,195 0 1,0 2,0z"/>
    <path stroke-width="18" d="m210,15v390m195-195H15M59,90a260,260 0 0,0 302,0 m0,240 a260,260 0 0,0-302,0M195,20a250,250 0 0,0 0,382 m30,0 a250,250 0 0,0 0-382"/>
    </svg>
```

Thanks!

Comment: add a viewBox attribute to the svg element: `viewBox="0 0 420 420"` and change the width and height to what you need: `width="17" height="17"` In fact you can set only the width.

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks, That works and so if u put it as an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've commented you need to add a viewBox attribute to the svg element. The value of the viewBox attribute is a list of four numbers: min-x, min-y, width and height and in this case should be equal to the bounding box of the group of paths + some extra space to acomodate the wide stroke.

```js
console.log(group.getBBox())
```

```css
body{background:black}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 420 420"  width="17"  fill="none" stroke="#dcdcdc">
  <g id="group">
    <path stroke-width="26" d="M209,15a195,195 0 1,0 2,0z"/>
    <path stroke-width="18" d="m210,15v390m195-195H15M59,90a260,260 0 0,0 302,0 m0,240 a260,260 0 0,0-302,0M195,20a250,250 0 0,0 0,382 m30,0 a250,250 0 0,0 0-382"/>
  </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: More resize/viewBox info: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/